# Sort Javascript object by keys

Tags: javascript

I have multi level object with structure like below

```
{
  "28300": {
    "ceiv": "7.89",
    "cenormal": "0 ",
    "cechange": "0.00"
  },
  "28400": {
    "ceiv": "7.89",
    "cenormal": "0 ",
    "cechange": "0.00"
  },
  "28500": {
    "ceiv": "98.60",
    "cenormal": "0.27 ",
    "cechange": "-2.21"
  },
  "28600": {
    "ceiv": "7.89",
    "cenormal": "0 ",
    "cechange": "0.00"
  },
  "28700": {
    "ceiv": "7.89",
    "cenormal": "0 ",
    "cechange": "0.00"
  }
}
```

How do I sort by ceiv in ascending and descending.

I have tried something like below

```
data.sort(({ ceiv: a }, { ceiv: b }) => b - a);
```

But its not sorting , thank you.

Comment: No it does not have  "28700": extra key.

Comment: Assuming the object above is `data`, then it does not have a `sort` method.

Comment: Looks like you need to convert your JSON to a javascript object. Then you can sort by key

Comment: You need to do a deep sort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299116/sort-deep-object-in-javascript

Comment: @Malcor Where did you find [JSON](http://json.org)?

Comment: The example data above, is not a javascript object, it's JSON, by the looks of it.

Comment: No it is an object, i just copied from console using copy(arr);